# Deploy Source in Manifest to Org - ended with exit code 1 and no response in problem tab

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx, vs-code, manifest

I have a local Salesforce DX project with a `package.xml` manifest file.

The project has been authorised against a fresh developer org.

I want to deploy all my local code in one go, so I am using the `Deploy Source in Manifest to Org` option.

When I right click on the  manifest file and select `Deploy Source in Manifest to Org` the response I get is not very helpful and there is nothing in the problems tab:

```
Starting SFDX: Deploy Source to Org

11:36:24.975 sfdx force:source:deploy --manifest c:\projects\sfdx\xxx\manifest\package.xml --json --loglevel fatal
11:36:42.111 sfdx force:source:deploy --manifest c:\projects\sfdx\xxx\manifest\package.xml --json --loglevel fatal ended with exit code 1
```

How can I deploy everyone in one go and get validation error messages back on what the issue is?

Comment: Did you get any Error message in PROBLEM Tab. Please provide the error message if you get it.

Comment: Can you try via command line using sfdx force:source:deploy -x path/to/package.xml? It will deploy all components listed in a manifest.

Comment: @TilakRaj nothing in the problem tab

Comment: @sanketkumar using the command line successfully returns the errors to the command line

Comment: And i believe it deploys all in one go. Right?

Comment: @sanketkumar Yes is does. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Robs I have this problem also - the deploy fails with no error in VSCode.  In the command line, it shows the errors fine.  Were you able to fix the error reporting in VS Code?

Comment: @NicolasGaller nope, I raised a [support issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1146) on github